# Core Image many times slower on first render

Tags: ios

I can't find any documentation from Apple to explain why this piece of code runs at different speeds depending on how many times its been run.

```
- (void)speedTest2:(CIImage*)source {
    NSTimeInterval start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();

    CIFilter* filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorInvert"];
    [filter setValue:source forKey:kCIInputImageKey];

    CGImageRef cgImage = [_context createCGImage:filter.outputImage fromRect:source.extent];
    UIImage* output = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
    if (cgImage)
        CFRelease(cgImage);
    _source.image = output;

    NSLog(@"time: %0.3fms", 1000.0f * (CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start));
}
```

#### Run times

- Fresh app install - first call to method = **206ms**
- App restarted - first call to method = **61ms**
- second call to method (3rd, 4th, ...) = **14ms**

The same source image is being used for every run.

I know Core Image concatenates the filter chain. Is this somehow being cached? Can I pre-cache this operation so users don't get hit with performance problems on their first app launch?

This one is making me crazy :(

Comment: perhaps dynamic loading of the Core Image framework on 1st use?  Try making CIFilter *filter something that is pre-initialized on load instead of instantiating a new object each time.

Comment: also, if you really want performance check out Brad Larsons GPUImage framework.  Open source.  Uses OpenGL/ES.  you can create a color invert filter fairly easily.  And it will be faster than CoreImage, hands down.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried multiple ways to pre-load the library and individual filter objects with no luck. Core Image waits until the last possible moment to do all its work so I don't see the performance hit until I actually render the final image. I would be interested to see how much faster the GPUImage framework is since both it and Core Image run on the GPU.

Comment: Do you call with the same CIImage or different ones? If it's the same I would say that CoreImage "caches" the CIImage, meaning on first call it is copied to a texture in the GPU and on secondary calls this texture is reused. GPU Memory will be cleaned if iOS needs the space, so it is possible the CIImage stays in GPU RAM. For the fresh App install: look into your cache directory, perhaps the pixelshader used by the filter is cached on first run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A portion of the overhead may be the image library itself loading. If the effects are implemented as pixel shaders, there may well be a compilation step going on behind the scenes.

This hidden cost is unavoidable, but you can choose to do it at a more convenient time. For example when the application is loading.

I would suggest loading a small image (1x1 px) and applying some effects to it during load to see if it helps.

You may also want to try the official Apple forums for a response.

Answer (score -2):

There are three ways to create context to draw outputImgae; `contextWithOptions:` this create on GPU or CPu which based on you deveice; `contextWithEAGLContext:; contextWithEAGLContext:` options: created on GPU; look at Core Image Programming Guide;

Comment: I'm aware of this and have tried all the different context rendering methods. The bottleneck is in preparing the Core Image filter chain for the first render. After that its pretty fast.

Comment: as you say, the reason may be your picture too larger;you can use the function UIImageJPEGRepresentation or UIImagePNGRepresentation .. to compress picture ,and then use the filter;hope this can help you .